# Why don't I get a whole number when determining the vibrational energy level of F2?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, thermodynamics, statistics

So I was playing around with some data and formulas and wanted to calculate the index for the wave number of the vibration of F2 that I got from [here](https://cccbdb.nist.gov/expvibs2x.asp#2007Iri:389), i.e. which allowed energy level n this corresponds to.

[image]

Permitted energy levels are given by:
$$\epsilon_n = h\nu\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right),\quad n = 1,2,3,\ldots \tag{1}$$
The given wave number ($893.9$ cm$^{-1}$) can be used to calculate $\epsilon$ with $1.986\times10^{-26}$ kJ$\,\cdot\,$cm (**however, now that I think about it a second time, I'm not so sure whether I can determine the energy of something like the wavenumber for vibrations of molecules such as electromagnetic waves via $h$ and $c$ so easily, which leads me to the question of how one is supposed to find out at what temperature/energy this wavenumber was determined using the above Web site?**):
$$\epsilon_n = 1.775\times10^{-20}\,\text{J}$$

Now I just have to convert (1) to $n$ and insert the values:
$$n = \frac{1.775 \times 10^{-20} \, \text{J}}{h \cdot c \cdot 89390 \ \text{m}^{-1}} - \frac{1}{2} = 0.499.$$
What am I doing wrong?

Edit: In the end, I can't do much with the value $893.9$ cm$^{-1}$ for F2 without knowing to which energy this frequency belongs. After all, I can generally only calculate an energy for electromagnetic waves via Plank's constant and $c$ with the help of the frequency, but here we are dealing with molecular oscillation; and as long as I don't know at which energy this frequency was measured, this tells me nothing about the nature of F2 (?)

I'm questioning how molecular vibrations can even be expressed in wave numbers $\text{cm}^{-1}$, a unit that seems more fitting for spatial measurements. I'm aware that electromagnetic waves have wave numbers tied to spatial propagation due to the relationship $\lambda v = c$. However, I'm struggling to comprehend how a molecule's vibration relates to this. Unlike electromagnetic waves that propagate spatially, how can molecular vibrations be associated with this unit which normaly represents energy? Is ν in (1) even the frequency associated with the molcular vibration or the frequency associated with the photon which is measured in IR Spectroscopy?

Comment: Link dead. It says: _Sorry. I lost your molecule. Please back up and try again._

Comment: @Qmechanic already noticed that strange behaviour, sometimes it works and sometimes not: https://cccbdb.nist.gov/expvibs2x.asp#2007Iri:389 or you go from the home site to experimental, vibrations and search for "F2"

Answer (score 1):

There seem to be quite a few misunderstandings. Your equation gives you the energy of the vibrational levels of a quantum harmonic oscillator as function of the quantum number.

$$
\epsilon_n = h\nu(n+1/2), \ \ n\in [0,1,2,...]
$$

Note that the allowed quantum numbers start at zero for an harmonic oscillator.

The unit of this expression is energy, not inverse centimeter. $\nu$ is a frequency and thus has the unit [1/s], i.e. inverse time. $h$ has unit [J s], i.e. time times energy, and the product $h\nu$ has thus simply [J], which can be converted to any other unit of energy.

Inverse centimeter are connected to energy using the relation between the speed of light $c$ to frequency $\nu$ and wave length $\lambda$.
$$
\lambda\nu=c.
$$

We can use this to associate energy with inverse length, and a valid unit for inverse length is inverse cm.

$$
h\nu = h\frac{c}{\lambda } = hc\frac{1}{\lambda} =hc\tilde \nu
$$
where $\tilde \nu = \frac{1}{\lambda}$ is the so called wavenumber and typically given in inverse cm.

Thus the equation in inverse cm is obtained by dividing $\epsilon_n$ by $hc$,

$$
\tilde \epsilon_n = \epsilon_n/(hc)  = \tilde \nu(n+1/2)
$$
and conversion from inverse centimeter to energy is achieved by multiplying with $hc$. But make sure that $hc$ is expressed in the according units i.e. you need to express the speed of light in [cm/s] instead of using the common [m/s] value.

Now back to your title question. The fundamental frequency determines the spacing between two consecutive energy levels
$$
\epsilon_{n+1} - \epsilon_n = h\nu,
$$

but it is not the energy of the harmonic oscillator. This is the energy required to induce a transition from state $n$ to state $n+1$.  It is not sensible to set
$$
\epsilon_n \stackrel{!}{=}h\nu
$$
This will always lead to $n=1/2$ and is not the quantum number of your state. The energy of the harmonic oscillator depends on its quantum number and you cannot say which energy the oscillator has or in which state it is without that number.

The equation for the energy is also completely independent of temperature, just as the fundamental frequency. Temperature enters the picture in a very different way and requires some understanding of statistical thermodynamics and the concept of density operators in quantum mechanics. But based on your question, I would recommend reading up on the basic quantum harmonic oscillator first using a text book, before considering more advanced concepts.

Comment: `Your equation gives you the energy of the vibrational levels of a quantum harmonic oscillator as function of the quantum number.` so $\nu$ was never supposed to be the actual frequency of let's say a diatomic molecule? Otherwise I can't get my head around how we could simply use $\lambda\nu=c$ for other things than photons, I mean how could a molecule swing as fast as a photon with the same energy when it has more mass?

Comment: @Leonard $\nu$ is the frequency of the vibration. And the vibration can be excited by absorption of photons with frequency $\nu$ and thus a photon energy of $h\nu$. Your last point is a bit confused. The frequency alone tells you nothing about the actual velocity of the particle that executes a periodic motion around a equilibrium position. You would also need the amplitude in such a case to determine the velocity. The case of a traveling wave is special, since there you have a direct connection of velocity, frequency and wavelength, but the harmonic oscillator is not a traveling wave.

Comment: Now that you mention it, it's true. I can have a pendulum with a high frequency but extremely small displacement or a pendulum with the same frequency but more displacement (this would have more energy) so the molecule oscillates with the same frequency (and therefore with the same energy hv) as the photon but the higher the reduced mass of the molecule, the smaller the amplitude if the energy stays the same as before?

Comment: It is kind of crazy that the molecule oscillates with the same frequency as the photon, after all it could have oscillated with a lower frequency and with a larger displacement/ stretching, energetically it would be the same.

Comment: @Leonard That is one of the essential features of quantum mechanics that differentiates it from classical mechanics. The frequency is a characteristic of the oscillator, and its also not possible to excite the transition using the same process with two photons, each having half the frequency, although both together would have the same energy as a single photon with the fitting frequency. You need  photons with the matching frequency.

Comment: Thank you. Assuming I have a molecule whose vibration can be excited at a frequency of x, and I have a laser that emits exactly frequency x, would it theoretically be sufficient to keep the laser on it for a long time until the molecular vibration amplitude becomes so high that it dissociates? I mean, to achieve higher vibration levels, I can't simply use photons with higher energy, because then the photon and molecular vibration frequencies would no longer match. So, how can higher states be reached other than, for example, keeping the laser on for an extended period?